# Is there an adjective describing that a word is in between "..."?

Tags: single-word-requests

Lets say I want to tell someone

> just spell the word within the "...".

is there an adjective so I can say

> Just spell the ... word

?

Comment: The word *quoted* may be enough.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: 
Ah, should I add this sidenote to my OP? That word came into my mind as first thought. But in this specific case I am telling someone something along the lines 'I want you to tell me first something like "its ok for me". So if it is, just quote the ... words.' Here I use the word quoted to tell them to just quote what I wrote there. But the first case when I am doing it is by my understanding not a quotation per se... Or is it? But even then.... "Quote the quoted words!" sounds irritating to me '^.^

Comment: So I rather am looking for an adjective describing the syntactical placement of the "", if there is any.

Comment: Like in "The paraphrased words".

Comment: Quoted words are the words inside quotation marks, not only the words that you quote after someone speaks or writes them. You could tell someone to enter the quoted password as their temporary PIN, and they will understand that they need to type the material inside the quotation marks (and not the marks themselves).

Comment: Consider posting it with that explanation then as answer... maybe? :)

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the word is *already* spelled out between quotation marks, it doesn't makes sense to ask how it's spelled. The examples provided aren't clear enough to understand what's being asked for.

Comment: 'enclosed', 'bounded' Put them in italics and say 'italicised'.

Comment: @Zaibis I'm sure you don't want to tell someone ‘*just spell the word within the "...".*’! Could you replace that with what you would **actually say?**

Comment: If the can see the "s, aren't they just copying the spelling too?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Doing it with "italicised" is a good idea. That should work for me. But still, I was asking IF there is such a word like italicised ofr words written in italic existing for words in quotation marks. Not what the way is to express my example. I am looking for a specific word if it exists. Not for a solution to my example.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Well, actually thats pretty much what I intend to say. Its along the lines "If you want me to do X, I want you to ask me something like "....". So go ahead and just copy paste the sentence within the "". "

Comment: So you **actually say** quote-dot-dot-dot-quote?

Comment: @Andrew Leach: exactly.

Comment: I mean I write it. Also dont know why its relevant for the question as I was just asking if there is such a word

Answer (score 1):

You could say "Just spell the *given* word."

This directs them to the word as a word rather than its meaning.